# How to get the next business day in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following test code. Basically I am checking when a new file is created in folder.  I need to know that if the file was created after 4pm display the next business day. Currently my code displays the next day, but I need to display the next business day. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$formatteddate = "{0:h:mm:ss tt}" -f (get-date)

if ($formatteddate -gt "4:00:00 PM"){
$(Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString('MMM d yyyy')
}
```

Comment: You mean Monday - Friday? How do you work with holiday?

Comment: this may be of use to you: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4j9usl/getdate_next_business_day/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to what jisaak said: "business day" is organization specific. Some organizations don't work on holidays that other organizations do. If you want to handle holidays correctly you'll need an explicit list of holidays for your business

Omitting the formatting details (which OP seems to understand) this should do it:

```
#  $date is input date
$nextBizDay = $date.adddays(1)

# You would probably want to generate the follow list programmatically,
#  instead of manually as done here
$holidays = 1,   <# New Years #>
            18,  <# MLK day 2016 #>
                 <# other holidays encoded as Day Of Year #>
            360  <# Christmas in a Leap Year #>
# An alternative to a list of holidays like this is to find a web service 
#  you can query to get the holidays for a given year

while ($nextBizDay.DayOfWeek -eq 'Saturday' -or
       $nextBizDay.DayOfWeek -eq 'Sunday' -or
       $nextBizDay.DayOfYear -in $holidays) {
  if ($nextBizDay.DayOfYear -gt 366) {
    throw "No next business day this year. Need to add additional logic"
  }
  $nextBizDay = $nextBizDay.adddays(1)
}
```

Comment: not so much worried about Holidays but I was able to get the next business day with this code as well `$formatteddate = "{0:h:mm:ss tt}" -f (get-date)

if ($formatteddate -gt "4:00:00 PM"){
$(Get-Date).AddDays(1 + $(1,2 -eq 7 - [int]$formatteddate.dayofweek) ).ToString('MMM d yyyy')
}`

Comment: @SikRikDaRula That should not work. You define `$formatteddate` as a string, so it does not have a `dayofweek` property to reference.

Comment: it works fine for me, Ill have to wait til Friday to truly test it