# Find and format next business date in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have found that I can get the next business date with

```
(Get-date)+"$(1+$(@(1,2-eq7-(Get-date).dayofweek)))"
```

But it is in a long date format

I Have found I can format a Date with:

```
Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd";
```

But how can I combine these two?

I tried

```
(Get-date)+"$(1+$(@(1,2-eq7-(Get-date).dayofweek)))" -format 'yyyyMMdd'
```

No luck!  So how do I do this.

My goal being to store the value in a variable like but with the next business day added.

```
$sdATE =  Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd";
```

Comment: I have found:
'{0:yyyyMMdd}'  -f (  (Get-date)+"$(1+$(@(1,2-eq7-(Get-date).dayofweek)))")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the next business day in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575352/how-to-get-the-next-business-day-in-powershell)

Comment: ((Get-date)+"$(1+$(@(1,2-eq7-(Get-date).dayofweek)))").ToString('yyyyMMdd') is a gross line of code. I sorta want to figure out why it works and sorta dont

Answer (score 1):

There is a misconception that a variable of date type has a format.

When **outputting** a variable of date type it is either applied the default date format or an explicitly defined one.

```
$sdATE =  Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
```

Your last command converts the date to a string, so without casting it again to a date (either im- or explicitly) you can't calculate with it.

```
> $sdATE.gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

To have your business date formula outputting your desired format you can use the  `.ToString()` method attached to a pair of parentheses enclosing the whole formula.

```
PS> ((Get-date)+"$(1+$(@(1,2-eq7-(Get-date).dayofweek)))").ToString('yyyyMMdd')
20170817
```