# powershell to calculate 20th business day from today

Tags: powershell

trying to calculate\determine 6th Business from today in powershell. 
is there a script\function available for same?

example : 
if today's date is 4th Feb 2018, 6th business day from today is 12th feb 2018. 
how do i get that date using powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the next business day in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575352/how-to-get-the-next-business-day-in-powershell)

Comment: Step 1: Make a function to find the next business day, such as from the link above.  Step 2: Do it in a loop 20 times.

Comment: Why does it say 20th day in the title and 6th in the text?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for your situation.
It adds 2 days if the current iteration lands on a Saturday and 1 day if it lands on a Sunday.  There may be a better way but I know this works.

Edit: I didn't think about it if you need to account for holidays let me know and I may be able to edit this script to include it.

```
$daystoadd = 7

$CurrentDate = Get-date

For ($i = 1; $i -le $daystoadd; $i++) {
    $CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.adddays(1)
    if ($CurrentDate.DayOfWeek -eq 'Saturday') {
        $CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.adddays(2)
    }
    if ($CurrentDate.DayOfWeek -eq 'Sunday') {
        $CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.adddays(1)
    }

}

$CurrentDate
```

Comment: I believe you are adding a day too many. I would say that the sixth business day after a Monday would be the Tuesday after, your code makes it the Wednesday after.

Answer (score 0):

@Sumanth specifically asks for the sixth business day, so this should do the trick:

```
function SixthBusinessDay($date)
{
    $daysToAdd = 8,8,8,8,8,10,9 
    $weekDay = $date.DayOfWeek.value__
    $sixtBusinessDay = $date.AddDays($daysToAdd[$weekDay])
    return $sixtBusinessDay
}
```

It's based on that all days require at least six days and one weekend to make it the sixth business day, but Friday requires two extra days and Saturday one extra day.

Running this:

```
(SixthBusinessDay (Get-date "2018-1-29")).ToString("dddd dd/MM")
(SixthBusinessDay (Get-date "2018-1-30")).ToString("dddd dd/MM")
(SixthBusinessDay (Get-date "2018-1-31")).ToString("dddd dd/MM")
(SixthBusinessDay (Get-date "2018-2-1")).ToString("dddd dd/MM")
(SixthBusinessDay (Get-date "2018-2-2")).ToString("dddd dd/MM")
(SixthBusinessDay (Get-date "2018-2-3")).ToString("dddd dd/MM")
(SixthBusinessDay (Get-date "2018-2-4")).ToString("dddd dd/MM")
```

gives the following result:

```
Tuesday 06-02
Wednesday 07-02
Thursday 08-02
Friday 09-02
Monday 12-02
Monday 12-02
Monday 12-02
```